# Filling a D2 array with reccursion in C++, works fine sometimes, throws exceptions others

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion

This code is part of a larger project, but I'm trying to get this bit to work first because everything after is trivial. Essentially I'm trying to use recursion to fill a 2D array of size 12 x 6 with random numbers from 1-12. The trick is, a number cannot repeat in a column or a row. The code works great with a larger pool of numbers, or a smaller array, but when I run it with those conditions, it throws an exception about half the time. I'm fairly sure that it's running into a situation where it can't find a number that meets the conditions so it just loops infinitely, but I'm not sure how to prevent that.

An example of the exceptions being thrown -

> Unhandled exception at 0x01232479 in Test -  Fill Array Recursively.exe: >0xC00000FD: Stack overflow (parameters: 0x00000001, 0x00602FE0).
>
> Exception thrown at 0x0FF0DB39 (ucrtbased.dll) in Test -  Fill Array >Recursively.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location 0x00600FFC.

Here is the code:

```
#include<iostream>
#include <ctime>  
#include <cstdlib>
using namespace std;

const int X = 12;
const int Y = 6;

//recursion function prototype
int randomArrayFunction(int Array[X][Y], int posParX, int PosParY);

int main() {
    //declarations

    int randomArray[X][Y];
    int posX = 0;
    int posY = 0;
    srand(static_cast<unsigned int>(time(NULL)));

    randomArrayFunction(randomArray, posX, posY);

        for (int i = 0; i < X; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < Y; j++) {
                cout << "  " << randomArray[i][j];
            }
            cout << endl;
        }


}

//recursion function defintion
int randomArrayFunction(int Array[X][Y], int posParX, int posParY) {
    int prevPosX = posParX - 1;
    int prevPosY = posParY - 1;
    int randomNumber = rand() % 12;
    
    if (posParY == Y)
        return 0;

    Array[posParX][posParY] = randomNumber;

    //Checks all previous numbers in a row for duplicates and reassigns a random number if one is found
    while (prevPosX >= 0) {
        if (posParX != 0 && Array[posParX][posParY] == Array[prevPosX][posParY]) {
            Array[posParX][posParY] = randomNumber;
            return randomArrayFunction(Array, posParX, posParY);
        }
        prevPosX--;
    }

    //Checks all previous numbers in a column for duplicates and reassigns a random number if one is found
    while (prevPosY >= 0) {
        if (posParY != 0 && Array[posParX][posParY] == Array[posParX][prevPosY]) {
            Array[posParX][posParY] = randomNumber;
            return randomArrayFunction(Array, posParX, posParY);
        }
        prevPosY--;
    }
    posParX++;

    if (posParX == X) {
        posParY++;
        posParX = 0;
    }

    return randomArrayFunction(Array, posParX, posParY);
}
```

I'm still relatively new to coding, and don't have much experience with recursion, so any help anyone can offer would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: out of curiosity: do they teach at uni/school that recursion is super cool? I never was a CS student, and recursion always makes me dizzy so I try to avoid it if a can

Comment: Not really no. I would normally use loops to be honest but the guidelines of the assignment specified recursion as the preferred method and since I don't have much experience with it I thought it would be worth trying.

Comment: Well, a way to generate a random permutation of some numbers is to list them in order and [`std::shuffle`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) them. Try thinking of a way to scale this up to 2D. I thought of a way to do it so I know it's possible. I just need to prove there is an equal chance to get all possible ways to fill the matrix.

Answer (score 0):

The issue you're having is that sometimes you run out of numbers to fill later entries in the array.  To have enough, you'll need at least (`X + Y - 1`) numbers available.  This is because when filling the last entry, you have `X - 1` numbers already in the row, and potentially `Y - 1` different numbers used in the column.  Since you've used `X - 1 + Y - 1` numbers already you'll need one more to fill the array.

This problem would be better solved using looping, not recursion.  And I won't get in to why using `rand()` is not a good idea these days.

Comment: rand() was just the easiest way I knew to generate a random number, if there is a better method I'm game. Would this same basic approach actually work with loops? Or am I still going to end up in the same position where I just don't have enough numbers to fill the array?

Comment: For this simple case, `rand()` is fine, but if you want to do any serious work with random numbers use the stuff in `<random>`.  Using loops will still run out of numbers, and if that happens your program will just run forever.  A simple check to verify that you have enough before you start will help with either solution.

Comment: The problem is it has to be a 6x12 array and I only have 12 options available. Essentially the assignment is to sort a fielding order for a baseball team given a certain number of players and position, with a bunch of stipulations on who can play what. Essentially it boils down to no two players being at the same position in any given inning, and no player can play the same position twice. The idea was to assign each of the 12 position a number, use this kind of fill technique to make sure no overlap occurred, and then use the number to fill an array of positions.

Comment: @jmas Then you'll need to come up with some way to avoid running out of numbers.  Which I'll leave as "an exercise for the reader".